# swift realm insert array in background thread use in main

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, realm, grand-central-dispatch

I have an array of objects received via rest response, which I want to insert into realm db in a **background** thread and use in a uicollectionview in **main** thread.
As soon as I receive response from rest, I call callback function and insert array into db in a background thread. 
The problem when I am trying to access in main thread property of object being inserted in background I'm getting exception (**see below**) which I assume because of object not yet inserted

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason:
>   'Realm accessed from incorrect thread.

The model

```
class User : Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var firstName: String?
    dynamic var lastName: String?

    required convenience init?(map: Map){
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        firstName <- map["firstName"]
        lastName <- map["lastName"]
    }
}
```

Inserting in a background thread...

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
  let realm = try! Realm()
  try! realm.write {
    realm.add(users)
  }
}
```

Rendering in UI...

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! UserViewCell

    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    cell.firstName.text = user.firstName
    cell.lastName.text = user.lastName
}
```

Please note that exception occur either on accessing firstName or lastName.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: Have you considered using a notificationToken?

Comment: That's the only thing I was thinking of but was not sure if it is good idea

Comment: This is what Realm's notification token is for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to create a new reference to your Realm instance on the main thread and fetch all users from realm using the newly created reference, so you will be accessing realm from the same thread.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! UserViewCell

    let users = try! Realm().objects(User.self)
    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    cell.firstName.text = user.firstName
    cell.lastName.text = user.lastName
}
```

Another solution is to use a `ThreadSafeReference` object to pass the `users` array from the background thread to the main thread. However, you can only create a single `ThreadSafeReference` to your collection of `users` if the type of `users` is either `Results` of `List`. See below code assuming `users` if of type `Results<User>`.

```
var usersRef: ThreadSafeReference<Results<User>>?
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    autoreleasepool{
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(users)
        }
        usersRef = ThreadSafeReference(to: users)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! UserViewCell

    let realm = try! Realm()
    guard let usersRef = usersRef, let users = realm.resolve(usersRef) else {return}
    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    cell.firstName.text = user.firstName
    cell.lastName.text = user.lastName
}
```