# Reaching Realm Results object from different thread gives crash

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a Results object in my viewModel defined and initialized as below

```
private var followings: Results<Following>!
// This runs in main thread
self.followers = try RealmHelper.getObjects(t: Follower.self)
```

In another function (after `self.followers` initialized and fulfilled) I try to get this followings object in different thread but gives bellow crash.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread.'

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { 
  let currentFollowersIds = self.followers.filter("friendShip.isFollowingYou == true")
}
```

**P.S:** If I get my objects with `realm.objects(T.self)`
It doesn't give crash.

**P.S 2:** I found that filtering gives the crash. If I remove filtering, It works but I need filtering. I tried assigning it to not-live array with `Array(followers).filter` but doesn't work also.

Comment: The vars and objects are confusing. There's a Results `Following` and then a `Follower` object and then a `var followings` and then another var `self.followers`. Then there's `RealmHelper` object - is that a singleton? If so, it will always be on the same thread so it's not clear why there are other threads involved. The `DispatchQueue` is totally unneeded on a query, it should only be used with writes so they don't tie up the UI. Can you update the code so we know what's what and clarify what's being asked and why there are multiple threads being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Realm objects can only be used from the same thread that they were fetched](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/fundamentals/realms/#threading).

So you have 2 main options, if you are going to use any of your data to populate UI, you'll have to fetch the objects in the main thread.

The other option is to create a new Realm instance and fetch the results again in the main thread, creating a Realm is supposed to be really lightweight.

You can also pass objects between threads but that is more complicated.

Comment: This is a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46141584/4855680

Comment: While there is good info here, it's old info. You can easily pass objects with [ThreadsafeReference](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/swift/latest/Structs/ThreadSafeReference.html) to the object and the coolest thing is [frozen](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/advanced-guides/threading/#frozen-objects) objects which allow full collections to be passed around and when needed, thaw them (released with 10.5.2). That being said there is nothing in the code in the question to indicate *where* the issue is, so more clarity in the question may lead to an updated/better answer.